# Org-mode inlinetask neither exporting nor archiving correctly

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I use emacs a lot and have been using Org-mode more and more. One of
the killer features for me is the `inlinetask`. These are TODOs which can
be placed anywhere in a document without being a part of the document
structure. I think of them as virtual sticky notes.

There are two problems that I've found that I can't solve:

1. an inline task at the end of a paragraph will cause the preceding
   paragraph to be merged with the proceeding paragraph when exporting
   (to ASCII, for example). Is there any way to fix this?

   For example, If I start out with the following:

   ```
   #+TITLE: 
   #+OPTIONS: inline:nil toc:nil author:nil

   Here is paragraph one. It has some
   mistakes so I need to make some changes.
   *************** TODO revise
   *************** END

   Here is paragraph two. I want it to
   remain a separate paragraph.
   ```

   Then I would expect this when I export

   ```
   Here is paragraph one. It has some mistakes so I need to make some
   changes.

   Here is paragraph two. I want it to remain a separate paragraph.
   ```

   But I get this:

   ```
   Here is paragraph one. It has some mistakes so I need to make some
   changes.
   Here is paragraph two. I want it to remain a separate paragraph.
   ```

   This problem is even more obvious when exporting to LaTeX because the two paragraphs will flow together with no obvious space between them.
2. inline tasks can't be archived. When I try to archive an inline
   task, I get an error: "The kill is not a (set of) tree(s)". Is there
   any way to archive inline tasks? The documentation notes:

   > Also, if you want to use refiling and archiving for inline tasks,  The END line must be present to make things work properly.

   All of my inline tasks have an END line, but I still get the error.

Comment: I've used `TODO` in the section headings in org-mode but I'm still learning about inlinetasks, i.e.  [org-inlinetask.el --- Tasks independent of outline hierarchy](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-inlinetask.el;hb=HEAD) . Would you provide an example of the syntax you're using? This might help others in the community.

Comment: @Melioratus Standard syntax. I just use the standard `C-c C-x C-t` to insert an inline task.

Answer (score 1):

I can only respond to the 2nd part of your question.  Inline tasks are not part of the Org tree structure.  So it cannot be archived.  To archive them, you need to archive the parent tree.  A work around might be to create a temporary tree that contains the inline task and archive it.

Comment: According to [the original announcement](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/12425/focus=12561), they _are_ part of the tree structure, just ignored for some purposes. Exporting them would simply require changing the value of the `ARCHIVE_OLPATH` property from the location in the tree when archiving to something generic like `INLINE_TASK`, possibly with the path of any parent tree that it may have been located under.

Comment: @snth You are misreading the announcement.  It is not part of the tree, that is why you have the [org-inlinetask-min-level](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-inlinetask-min-level) variable.  In any case, that announcement is outdated, and predates the "new" exporter by years.